# Prevent Trombone Routing with L2 DCI

Tags: dci

I would like to redesign a network that has workstations, servers, mgmt interfaces--lots of stuff-- in a single vlan. And, as noted, this single vlan spans an L2 DCI. But if I break all this stuff out into seperate vlans, then inter-vlan routing will be necessary. So, I would like to route between vlans without transiting the DCI. I recall hearing about a method for doing this that involved mac filtering to cause dual-active hsrp. Does anyone know the details of this method? Is there any downside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct there is something called FHRP isolation, where you block the messages of your FHRP between the Datacenter and in turn create a Dual active gateway's, one in each DC. The nodes in each DC can egress L3 in it's own DC.

From my point of view and experience, I recommend everyone doing this to try to minimize the tromboning of traffic between sites. Makes sense that traffic f.ex between vlan in one DC don´t need to traverse to another DC to egress it's L3.

Now in Cisco world you see this FHRP isolation accompanied with OTV (basically a way to send L2 across L3 without expanding the broadcast domain). I have seen some documentation on doing this with Port ACL's, mac acl on other platforms but can´t find it any more.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Data_Center/DCI/whitepaper/DCI_1.html#wp1186074
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Data_Center/DCI/4.0/EMC/EMC_2.html#wp1261581

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is not a way to do this without it being a huge kludge.

My suggestion would be that since you're already renumbering things, bite the bullet and renumber at each side of the L2 link.

Other questions will come up when renumbering, but it's worth it.